# calling some javascript from check/unchecked input html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my code thus far:

http://jsfiddle.net/YBGm4/4/

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#world-map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        hoverOpacity: 0.9,
        hoverColor: false,
        markerStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#F8E23B',
                stroke: '#383f47'
            }
        },
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        zoomMax: 30,

        <!--DO THIS ON CHECKMARK (so on load)-->
        /*
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: countriesvisited,
                scale: ['#B1C9C0', '#41a62a'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
        },
        */
        <!--------------------------->

        <!--DO THIS ON UNCHECKMARK-->
        /*
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: countriesvisited,
                scale: ['#B1C9C0'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
        },
        */
        <!--------------------------->

        markers: [{
            latLng: [49.1840, -123.0110],
            name: 'Current City: Vancouver'
        }]
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').fancyfields();
});
```

HTML

```
    <div id="world-map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
<br/>
<h2>Checkboxes</h2>
<div id="myForm">
    <input id="Checkbox" name="Checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox" style="display; none;" />
    <label>Countries I have Been To</label>
</div>
```

I have a checkbox object there. When checked I would like to to execute the code under

and when unchecked execute the code under

both codes correspond to the code in the /* */ area. if this makes sense.

I think taking a look at the code it will make sense what I am trying to do. I tried to strip it as much as possible for simplicity.

THANKS!

Comment: Likely, you won't be able to do the code as you think. The code that is sectioned out into `do on check/do on uncheck` is part of an object literal; likely, a set of configurations/optiosn. In order to achieve the desired effect, the `.vectorMap()` method would need to allow you to update that object literal.

Comment: (NVM misread!) Never used vectorMap plugin, but I'm sure there are events you can hook into. See: http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/. Maybe onMarkerClick?

Comment: here is a example (kinda): http://jvectormap.com/examples/usa-unemployment/ However they use a slider... So I don't know how to implement it into my code.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The simplest thing would be to use the [jQuery .on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).</s>

Doing so would look something like this:

```
$('input[type="checked"]').on('change', function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        // When checked, run this
    } else {
        // When unchecked, run this
    }
});
```

**EDIT**: Forked your JS fiddle to give an example of how to tie into the FancyFields checkbox change events. Looked briefly into the issue of updating the map, but am not sure I understand how it works enough to give much insight to that. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zQGV3/4/

Comment: Not sure how to fit that into my code. does the INPUT ID get used? Because the goal is to have more buttons - so I need to specify to do something IF a certain button is pushed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's going to work since he uses jqfancyfields plugin. They have a different way to bind the check event, which is annoying. http://www.jqfancyfields.com/examples-docs/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YBGm4/9/

Here is some annotated code that I added in your jQuery ready event:

```
// First we need to get mapObject to manipulate the map
// This was shown here: http://jvectormap.com/examples/usa-unemployment/
var mapObject = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');

// Now you need to add change event on your checkboxes. For simplicity, I just 
// did checkbox 1
// Now you can't use jQuery change event, since you are using `fancyfields`
// See docs here: http://www.jqfancyfields.com/examples-docs/
$("#Checkbox1").fancyfields("bind", "onCheckboxChange", function (input, isChecked){
    if (isChecked) {
         // If the checkbox is checked, we setScale to the original values
         mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale(['#B1C9C0', '#41a62a']);                         
    } else {
         // If the checkbox is not checked, we setScale to the some other values. 
         // I changed them, because the ones you used weren't showing up clearly.
         mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale(['#00000', '#ff0000']);               
    }
});
```

Note that I only used `setScale` here since your map region changes only dealt with the scale parameters. If you need to change the region values, you can do this: `mapObject.series.regions[0].setValues(countriesvisited)` or whatever.

Also note that I only gave an example using 1 checkbox. I'm assuming you know how to add your logic to the rest of the checkboxes.

**Edit 2**

Here is an attempt to explain what is happening:

First you need to edit the map object directly, which means you need to get it from the vectorMap class. For whatever reason the documentation doesn't explain this. But this is what is done in the usa-employment example.

```
var mapObject = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

Now that we the map object, we can change the series and regions data you set up. Once again refer to the `usa-employment` example on how this works. Additionally `console.log` can be helpful to see what methods and properties are on the object.

Based on your config, you only have one region, so we can access it like this:

```
var yourRegion = mapObject.series.regions[0];
```

Now the region object has some properties which you can inspect using your console:

```
console.log(yourRegion);
```

If you look carefully, you will see that it has two methods that can be helpful `setScale` and `setValue`. In this case you only change the scale, so we can do the following:

```
mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale(['#00000', '#ff0000']);
```

In terms of you example where you only have color value in the array, it did not seem to be working for me. Maybe you need more than 1 value in the array?

Now the other issue was working with the checkboxes. You can pretty much just copy the example given in the `jqfancyfields` documention: http://www.jqfancyfields.com/examples-docs/. Unfortunately the plugin makes the default jquery change events the checkboxes not work..

Here is what the syntax looks like:

```
$("#you-checkbox-element-id").fancyfields("bind", "onCheckboxChange", function (input, isChecked){
    if (isChecked) {
     // Logic for if checked                      
    } else {
     // Logic for if not checked              
    }
});
```

Hopefully that makes all the parts clearer for you. Ask if it is not.