# control map with a check mark button

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I  am still trying to make this happen :

http://jsfiddle.net/Vh79z/10/

As you can see- there is a map and a checkmark box. I want the check mark box to control the color of the countries.

For example: when checked (checked on load) I want it to highlight certain countries on the map. And when unchecked to display them in a different color.

```
            new jvm.WorldMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        container: $('#mymap'),
        backgroundColor: '#314F73',
        zoomMax: 40,
        markers: markers,
        markerStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#ffffff'
            }
        },
        series: {
            regions: [{
                scale: {
                    '1': '#B1C9C0',
                        '2': '#41a62a'
                },
                attribute: 'fill',
                values: data1['countriesvisited']
            }]
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').fancyfields();
    var mapObject = $('#mymap').jvm.WorldMap('get', 'mapObject');
    $("#Checkbox1").fancyfields("bind", "onCheckboxChange", function (input, isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            console.log(mapObject.series.regions[0]);
            mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale({
                '1': '#ffffff',
                    '2': '#000000'
            });
        } else {
            mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale({
                '1': '#000000',
                    '2': '#ffffff'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So using the above code:

On load it would load WITH all the: '1' parameter countries with COLOR #B1C9C0 '2' parameter countries with COLOR #41A62A

on checkmark: '1' parameter countries with COLOR #ffffff '2' parameter countries with COLOR #000000

on uncheck: '1' parameter countries with COLOR #000000 '2' parameter countries with COLOR #ffffff

Well that's what I want it to do. I am not sure I am getting the info from the map correctly though.

please help !

Comment: I thought I answered this question yesterday. Did you check out my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640210/calling-some-javascript-from-check-unchecked-input-html/21640588#21640588

Comment: It's possible I misunderstood what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Ok I fixed the problem. Here is an update jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vh79z/16/

The issue was that the setScale method was not added to the `OrdinalScale` object. This caused an error to be thrown when we tried to set the scale in the region object.

This is a bug, so I just added the `setScale` method myself. It looks like this:

```
jvm.OrdinalScale.prototype.setScale = function(scale) {   
    this.scale = scale;
};
```

**EDIT 1**

Here is an updated fiddle based on your updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/Vh79z/13/

If you uncheck code box, then countries turn black and white. If you check it back the colors are reversed. At least that's what I think you're looking for.

This is basically the same solution as for your previous question. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YBGm4/9/

I changed this:

```
scale: {
    '1': '#B1C9C0',
    '2': '#41a62a'
},
```

To this:

```
scale: ['#B1C9C0', '#41a62a'],
```

The reason I made this change is because these create different scale types. The one with the array is the `jvm.ColorScale` object, which is what I think you're looking for. The object syntax creates an `jvm.OrdinalScale` object.

Also there was a syntax bug here:

```
$('#mymap').jvm.WorldMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

Should be:

```
$('#mymap').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

Also I changed the following (for some reason it didn't like the ordinal scale syntax):

```
   if (isChecked) {
        console.log(mapObject.series.regions[0]);
        mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale({
            '1': '#ffffff',
                '2': '#000000'
        });
    } else {
        mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale({
            '1': '#000000',
                '2': '#ffffff'
        });
    }
```

To this:

```
if (isChecked) {
    mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale(['#ffffff', '#000000']);                         
} else {        
   mapObject.series.regions[0].setScale(['#00000', '#ffffff']);               
}
```

Comment: ya how do i do it with the jvm.ordinalscale object? I want to use the array color picker and not the scale.

Comment: Not sure, I tried a few things, but it just didn't like it. I'll try again.

Comment: would be awesome, because right now I can't select the same color in the setScale([]). Which I would need for unselected countries.  I guess I could change the color difference by a negligible hex value : but I hate work arounds....

Comment: One issue is that the `ordinalScale` doesn't have a setScale function, which is why it throws an error when I try to use it. The `colorScale` actually has the `setScale` function, which is why it works.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're going for now and why Color scale won't work for you here.

Comment: ya, Why black though? that's kinda weird. hmm... I didn't know it was going to be so tough to do this. Posted it on many forums with no answer yet. Yours is the closest I can get - if I offset the hex value by a negligible amount I can get away with it - but like I said, seems like a silly work around.

Comment: Did you check my updated fiddle? I figured out how to use the OrdinalScale. It's a bug in the code, but I patched it. Here is the link again: http://jsfiddle.net/Vh79z/16/ (Try changing the colors since I just used black and white. You should be able to use whatever colors you want now.)

Comment: oh that is so huge. thank you so much for your time and effort - helped a tone. I gotta ask, where was the code? and how did you patch it? I don't see any difference anywhere really....

Comment: The big change in the latest version is I added this function: `jvm.OrdinalScale.prototype.setScale`. It's documented in the answer.

Comment: ok sweet. thanks again :) works great now. I tried to past it in my wordpress blog (the code that is) but it doesn't work with the new syntax. Any thoughts to why that may be? very perimilary debugging so far - but if you have an idea on the top of your head... please share?

Comment: Not sure, maybe check that all your html elements have the right ids.

Comment: ya they def do, copied it verbatim from jsfiddle... I will try to fiddle around some more :)

Comment: should this javascript go in head or body tags? I never quite understood that.

Comment: I created this gist for you. Hope it helps. Need to get some sleep now. https://gist.github.com/richard-to/8899606